# jQuery Instances Overwriting Eachother

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, instances

I have the above code which runs and changes icons to loading icons and then to other icons if its successful. Anyway, it works absolutely fine on a single instance; however, the moment I click two (or more) for example, it will leave the first instance with the loading icon and then the last instance will get its icon changed twice.

I think I understand whats happening and that is that my variables are getting over-written with new values. How do I fix this? Shouldnt each instance of the function have its own set of variables? Right now it seems to me that the variables (init_elem,closest_td,closest_tr) are global and hence being overwritten?

"$(this)" loses its context and hence the reason why I am assigning it to variables.
I am using this on jqGrid and hence the need for .on() because having it 'normally' doesnt work.
I have tried to use $.proxy; but I have never used it before and I cant seem to get it work properly since console.log'ing $(this).html() is showing the dialog html instead of the anchor html.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#acquire-dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true
    });
});

$(document).on('click','.acquire-confirmation', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    init_elem = $(this);
    closest_td = $(init_elem).closest("td");
    closest_tr = $(init_elem).closest("tr");
    process_id = $(this).attr("rel");

    $("#acquire-dialog").dialog('option', 'buttons', {
        "Confirm" : function() {
            restore_html = $(init_elem).closest("td").html();
            $(closest_td).html('<img class="qmark" title="Loading..." src="images/loading.gif">');
            $.post(
                'includes/_add_ajax.php', 
                {section: 'acquire_document', process_id: process_id},
                function(data){
                    $("#ajax_notifications").freeow(data.subject,data.message,{classes: [data.type] });
                    if (data.type == 'success')
                    {
                        $(closest_tr).find("div:first")
                            .removeClass('icon_status_0')
                            .addClass('icon_status_2')
                            .attr('title','You have acquired access to this document.');
                        if (typeof data.status !== "undefined")
                        {
                            var document_status = ['A','B','C'];

                            $(closest_td).prev().html(document_status[data.status]);
                            if (data.status == 1)
                                $(closest_td).html('<a class="qmark" target="_blank" title="Generate a return for this document." href="includes/generate_return.php?id='+ process_id +'"><img src="images/icon_pdf.png" border="0" /></a>');
                            else
                                $(closest_td).html('<img class="qmark" title="You can only generate a return for a document once its been served or a return of non-service has been issued." src="images/icon_question.png">');
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        $(init_elem).closest("td").html(restore_html);
                },
                'json'
            );
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Cancel" : function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    });

    $("#acquire-dialog").dialog("open");

});
```

This is what Ive tried in regards to $.proxy():

```
$.proxy($("#acquire-dialog").dialog("open"),this);
```

and

```
$.proxy($("#acquire-dialog").dialog("open"),$(this));
```

and lastly on the event bind as well, though I dont think this is right:

```
$(document).on('click','.acquire-confirmation', $.proxy(function(event) { ... },this)); // and $(this)
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use
**var** init_elem = $(this);

Comment: Without the `var` the variables are indeed global

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `var` keyword otherwise your variables will be overwritten

You can learn about variable scope in JavaScript here
[What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)

Comment: That was probably the issue then! I did end up using a workaround by making the said variables arrays and passing through an ID. But I will implement the above fix ASAP!